# jQuery, internet explorer and navigation tabs

Tags: jquery, html, opacity

I am currently putting together a navigation for a website. navigation is very straight forward with a tabbed style menu. As you hover over each tab, the tab fades from Red with White text - to White with Red text. When you remove your mouse it should then fade back from white button with red text, to red button with white text.
I have all the jQuery written and working. The major problem lies with in Internet Explorer. It is driving me crazy!

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.button-text').fadeIn();
                $('.red-text').hide();
                $('.red-text2').hide();
                $('.red-text3').hide();
                $('.red-text4').hide();
                $('.red-text5').hide();
                    <!-- toggle visibility of red text on hover -->
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button').hover(function(){
                        $('.red-text').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button').mouseleave(function(){
                        $('.red-text').hide();
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button2').hover(function(){
                        $('.red-text2').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button2').mouseleave(function(){
                        $('.red-text2').hide();
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button3').hover(function(){
                        $('.red-text3').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button3').mouseleave(function(){
                        $('.red-text3').hide();
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button4').hover(function(){
                        $('.red-text4').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button4').mouseleave(function(){
                        $('.red-text4').hide();
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button5').hover(function(){
                        $('.red-text5').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                    $('.white-hover-nav-button5').mouseleave(function(){
                        $('.red-text5').hide();
                    });         
            });
```

the white tab is .white-hover-nav-button, the text is red-text.

Inside of internet explorer the user clicks on a link, and the page changes. If the user doesnt move there mouse at all while the page changes, the white button appears again but there is no text inside of it unless you move your mouse off the button and then back on. Does any one have any idea why it would be doing this? I have been trying to figure it out all weekend as I continue to build up my site. It works perfectly in FF and Chrome, but IE is a huge fail as usual.

This is so terrible. Clearly it should be working. Is it an opacity problem in IE? I dont think so, it works otherwise. wtf.

All I want is so when the user clicks the tab and they are directed to the next page, I dont want the text inside the button to disappear and for some reason it does. even tho I have $('red-text').show(); one page load.

Comment: I assume these Items are all together in the HTML. You should really use a single class name or something much more simple and make one call to do it all. that's is way more .hover's than you really need

Comment: That jQuery code could definitely be re-written to be more efficient.  Create a Fiddle of your nav on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it definitely could be written more efficiently. But for proof of concept etc, this works for the time being. I am triyng to get IE 8 support. It works well across all browsers, but IE 8 doesnt have that second lag as the page loads before you can click a link like chrome and firefox do.

Answer (score 0):

houstonla.wpengine.com

if you check it in IE 8, and click a tab in the navigation you will see that the text disappears and the button just remains white. It is very strange. I can not seem to figure out why it is acting this way.